# Dynamically loading stickers for iMessage

Tags: xcode, imessage, imessage-extension

As we can create simple iMessage stickers by just dragging images in the new template(Sticker Pack Application) provided by XCode. Is there a way that rather than having images in XCode, we can have images on a server and the pack gets whatever is there on the server as users open the sticker pack on the devices.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you will need a proper iMessage extension, not a simple sticker pack. This way you'll be able to handle all the logic to load the collection of stickers. But it's completely possible, just a bit more complicated as Apple don't handle that part.
You could also put your stickers into an in-app purchase and keep data on apple server, but you'll still need to handle the logic to show stickers. Also, by doing that way, it will be more tricky to show preview of stickers ;)